# What is the name of Design style used in Monument valley opening? Other examples?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, typekit

I am designing a poster and saw recently a bunch of designs using very thin white font and some thin logo illustration-type ordeal on a dark background. A lot of these seem to be on a sort of "sky-like" background and many have used objects that look like mountains.

The only example I can think of is from Monument valley-

[image]

But I know there are a large number of people who have used this style in video games, websites, etc. Is there a name for this? What are some other really clean examples for inspiration?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have other images or can you note the precious characteristics of the style you're looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for thin white lines and font on a gradient background.. seen in many video games

Answer (score 2):

I think the style is called **Geometric** Design or **minimal** design(even though not all of them use thin typeface)

search for geometric POSTER design, geometric WEBSITE design and geometric BROCHURE design on image search sites (pinterest & google images are my Go To sites for this) and you should get plenty of examples

https://www.pinterest.com/explore/geometric-poster-design/

you can also use the examples used in this article to see how and for what they have used such elements (I've learnt so much from this article)

http://blog.visme.co/composition-rules-for-non-designers/

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about the name of this style but I'd just describe it as flat gradient graphics.

Answer (score 0):

**isometric and flat!!!**

When it comes to gameplay of monument valley whole game is designed in isometric style! [Check out examples](https://in.pinterest.com/search/pins/?q=isometric%20game%20ui&rs=typed&term_meta[]=isometric%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=game%7Ctyped&term_meta[]=ui%7Ctyped)

and when you talk of its UI then all the elements are designed on FLAT UI base with Minimal White Colors!

Comment: OP is not asking about the isometric part of the design